# Методы hasNext() и Next()

Tags: java

**Задача:**

> На вход подаётся последовательность слов. Посчитайте общее количество введённых слов.
> **Примечание**. Так как маркер конца последовательности в этой задаче отсутствует, будет удобно воспользоваться методом `hasNext()`."

**Моё решение:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MyStudy {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = 0; //счетчик слов
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            a++;
        }
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

В гугле гуглил=) Не могу понять, как остановить `hasNext()`? Получается бесконечный цикл.

Comment: ага, а считывание строки-то из сканера где? hasNext только проверяет есть ли что-то или нет. а считывания тут нет. Как только появится - и бесконечность исчезнет

Comment: Вот поэтому я и не могу понять, из всего, что читал, понял, что hasNext() проверяет есть ли что то или нет, и возвращает true или false, по моей логике он проверяет  есть, ли что то на вводе и если есть то true и цикл выполняется. А если ничего не ввели, то false и он остановился. добавил String s = sc.next(); в цикл. Но он всё равно ждёт пока я что то дам ему на вход.

Comment: Врёшь ты всё)) показывай весь код и что даёшь на вход

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский 
    `public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       int a = 0;
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String s = sc.next(); // Если здесь, то он ждёт ввод=( 
            a++;
        }
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}` Извините, что не могу код вставить в сообщение по человечески.

Comment: Пишу в IntelliJ IDEA, не выдает счетчик слов. Из цикла не выходит, а на курсе закинул задачу в тестировщик. Прошла. Вообще мозг взорвался...

Answer (score 0):

> Пишу в IntelliJ IDEA, не выдает счетчик слов.

Проблема тут не столько в `hasNext` (хотя, чтобы `hasNext` работал, нужна ещё ему в пару `sc.next()`, `sc.nextLine()` и подобный метод, который будет считывать данные), сколько в том, где происходит исполнение программы.

`System.in` - используется для работы с консолью, для получения ввода с консоли.

В IDEA, понятно, консоли нет (во всяком случае в intellij idea я не припомню). Поэтому он и не может ничего считать. Если на вход в IDEA подать строку `new Scanner("123 4 555");` то будет работать и в самой *IDE*

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно считать 1 строку из консольного буфера и закрыть его. Для удобного использования методов сканера передай считанную строку в новый сканер и дальше используй его

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = scanner.nextLine();
scanner.close();
Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(line);
String codeMessage = "";
String result = "";
while (scanner1.hasNext()){}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Передаем в обьект класса Scanner строку "..."
        Scanner sc=new Scanner("и цикл выполняется. А если ничего не ввели, то"); 
        int a = 0;
        while (sc.hasNext()){    //Пока есть что считывать
            String c=sc.next();  // с  присвоить слово
            a++;                 // счетчик
        }
        System.out.println(a);   //вывод счетчика в консоль
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы.